# Need help including images using pdflatex

Tags: graphics

I have a picture of a chart I want to include in my beamer presentation

I have included the following in my preamble

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{C:/Latexpics/}
```

I am using MikTeX, when I use the command

```
\includegraphics{Chart}
```

I get an error saying `file chart not found`

Obviously i have something set  up wrong, in the file path i have tried `.jpeg`, `.png`, and `.pdf`

I am using `pdflatex`

any help on where my mistake is would be immensely apprec

Comment: The correct syntax should be `\graphicspath{{C:/Latexpics/}}` with an additional set of braces

Comment: Why don't put the image in a sub folder of your main input file? For example, if you put in `Images` sub folder, then you set `\graphicspath{{Images/}}`.

Comment: I corrected the \graphicspath command, it still gives me the same error. Which file type should i place in the folder? Is should i be including the extension type somewhere. Thanks for the quick responses, I am fairly new to latex and have never been able to figure out including images

Comment: Disregard, the fix worked

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to include images is just to make sure the image is in the same directory as your `.tex` file. Then when you are including your graphics, you don't have to bother with a path at all. Just have

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
...
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{chart.pdf}
```

and everything should be fine.